# Table Name Includes Date

Tags: sql

Sorry for any incorrect terms as I am not proficient in SQL...

I have a query that I need to run daily, however the table that I need to query includes todays date.  Normally I run:

```
SELECT m.displayName, a.source, count(a.agentGuid)
FROM ntEventLog20120725 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN machNameTab AS m ON a.agentGuid = m.agentGuid
WHERE a.eventTime > DATEADD(hour, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY a.agentGuid, m.displayName, a.source
HAVING COUNT(a.agentGuid) > 1000
ORDER BY m.displayName
```

However the table I want to query each day is different.  Todays table is `ntEventLog20120725`, tomorrows will be `ntEventLog20120726`.  I know how to get the date in that format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, getDate(), 112)
```

I just do not know how to combine the two together so that I can schedule this to run everyday.

Comment: do you create table per day? Sounds like bad design issue. Do you consider redesign?

Comment: This is sql-server? This would be simpler to build client side, how/from what are you running the SQL?

Comment: Yes, there is a table created every day... not my design but needed as there are thousands of machines reporting data into these tables.  Plus it makes it easier to archive and remove the table after a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this using dynamic query. though using dynamic query is not a good practice. But I guess that is the only option here

```
declare @date_val char(8)
select @date_val=convert(varchar,getDate(),112)

exec('
SELECT m.displayName,a.source,count(a.agentGuid) from ntEventLog'+@date_val+' a LEFT OUTER JOIN machNameTab m ON a.agentGuid = m.agentGuid WHERE a.eventTime > DATEADD(hour, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY a.agentGuid, m.displayName,a.source
HAVING COUNT(a.agentGuid) > 1000
ORDER BY m.displayName')
```

As  triclosan mentioned in the comment, you should consider redesigning the table. Not a good practice to have tables for each day

Answer (score 0):

One way is to build the query and execute.

Please try like:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
set @var ='select * From '+convert(varchar,getDate(),112)
exec (@var)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change the desing, the only way is to use dynamic sql

```
declare @table varchar(100), @sql varchar(8000)
set @table='ntEventLog'++convert(varchar,getDate(),112)
set @sql='
SELECT 
    m.displayName,a.source,count(a.agentGuid) 
from '+@table+' a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN machNameTab m ON a.agentGuid = m.agentGuid 
WHERE 
    a.eventTime > DATEADD(hour, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
GROUP BY 
    a.agentGuid, m.displayName,a.source 
    HAVING COUNT(a.agentGuid) > 1000 
ORDER BY m.displayName'
exec(@sql)
```

Also make sure to read thios post www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql